# Maximum amd Minimum number finding by digits

Tags: arrays, c, string, for-loop, while-loop

Accept a four digit integer from user and show the maximum and minimum number formed by those digits. ( Digits should be unique in the taken number)

Comment: Hello. You are not welcome at Stack Overflow, because copy/pasting your homework and dumping it on unpaid volunteers, expecting them to do it for you, is incredibly rude. We don't tolerate rudeness here. Also, questions need to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not goign to do your homework (you could at least ask a question and show us your research).

But you could search for scanf function to take user input.
After that you could with easely store the user input inside an array and when the array is full do the sort (search sorting array in C you will have a lot of result).